# Groovy clash between automatic property getter, local variables, and closures?

Tags: properties, groovy, closures

Groovy seems to have some very unpleasant behavior associated with "Groovy Beans" and closures that can cause it to mask local variables in certain circumstances.

Is this known behavior and is there some documentation somewhere that details this stuff? I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what wasn't working...

Consider the following code:

```java
class TestClass {

    def doIt(Closure closure) {
        closure.setDelegate(this)
        closure.call()
    }

    def getRevision() {
        return "testclass revision"
    }
}

def testIt() {
    def revision = "testit revision"

    println "1: " + revision + " (expect: testit)"

    TestClass tester = new TestClass()
    tester.doIt {
        println "2: " + getRevision()  + " (expect: testclass)"
    }

    println "3: " + revision + " (expect: testit)"

    tester.doIt {
        println "4: " + revision + " (expect: testit)"
        revision = getRevision()
        println "5: " + revision + " (expect: testclass)"
        println "6: ${getRevision()} (expect: testclass)"
        println "7: " + getRevision() + " (expect: testclass)"
    }

    // expect to have been set to testclass value in previous closure
    println "8: " + revision + " (expect: testclass)"

    tester.doIt {
        println "9: ${getRevision()} (expect: testclass)"
        println "10: " + getRevision() + " (expect: testclass)"
    }

    println "11: " + revision + " (expect: testclass)"
}

testIt()
```

Running this code produces the following output:

```
1: testit revision (expect: testit)
2: testclass revision (expect: testclass)
3: testit revision (expect: testit)
4: testit revision (expect: testit)
5: testit revision (expect: testclass)
6: testit revision (expect: testclass)
7: testit revision (expect: testclass)
8: testit revision (expect: testclass)
9: testclass revision (expect: testclass)
10: testclass revision (expect: testclass)
11: testit revision (expect: testclass)
```

My main problem is with 5/6/7. It seems that simply using the local `revision` variable within the closure "hides" the `getRevision()` method in the delegate and replaces it with a bean-style auto-generated `getRevision()` to match the `revision` "property". If I don't use the `revision` variable, calls to `getRevision()` do not invoke this bean behavior.

Any insight or links to documentation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Groovy closures [have a `resolveStrategy` property](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#setResolveStrategy%28int%29) that can be used to control the resolution order. The default strategy is to look-up the property from the "owning" object and only if it cannot be found there to use the delegate. I believe that setting this to [`DELEGATE_FIRST`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html#DELEGATE_FIRST) will get the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't help. I think the problem here is at compile time: using both `revision` and `getRevision()` within the closure makes the groovy compiler think it has to generate a getter for the `revision` variable , which then hides the delegate's version.